# Design-time change of wndproc make Visual Studio crash

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, compact-framework, windows-ce

I've successfully changed the wndproc address in a custom control at run-time. But my problem occurs when trying to implement this at design-time. If I drop the control to a form Visual Studio (2008) crashes. (WinCE 5.0, CF 2.0)

**Win32 namespace**

(Example only)

```
Friend Class NativeMethods

    Friend Shared ReadOnly Property IsDesignTime() As Boolean

    Friend Shared ReadOnly Property IsRunTime() As Boolean

    Friend Shared Function GetWindowLong(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal nIndex As Integer) As Integer
        If (NativeMethods.IsDesignTime) Then
            Return user32.GetWindowLong(hWnd, nIndex)
        ElseIf (NativeMethods.IsRunTime) Then
            Return coredll.GetWindowLong(hWnd, nIndex)
        Else
            Throw New Exception()
        End If
    End Function

    Private Class coredll
        <DllImport(DLLNAME, EntryPoint:="GetWindowLongW", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True)> _
        Friend Shared Function GetWindowLong(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal nIndex As Integer) As Integer
        End Function
        Friend Const DLLNAME As String = "coredll.dll"
    End Class

    Private Class user32
        <DllImport(DLLNAME, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True)> _
        Friend Shared Function GetWindowLong(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal nIndex As Integer) As Integer
        End Function
        Friend Const DLLNAME As String = "user32.dll"
    End Class

End Class
```

Both *IsDesignTime* and *IsRunTime* returns correct values.

**Custom control**

```
Public Class SystemControl
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Control

    Friend Sub New()
        Me.m_borderStyle = Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None
        Me.m_isDisposed = False
        Me.m_isHandleCreated = False
    End Sub

    Public Property BorderStyle() As BorderStyle
        Get
            Return Me.m_borderStyle
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As BorderStyle)
            If (value <> Me.m_borderStyle) Then
                Me.m_borderStyle = value
                Me.UpdateStyles()
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property DesignMode() As Boolean
        Get
            Return (((Not Me.Site Is Nothing) AndAlso Me.Site.DesignMode) OrElse StaticMethods.IsDesignMode(MyBase.Parent))
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property IsDisposed() As Boolean
        Get
            Return Me.m_isDisposed
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property IsHandleCreated() As Boolean
        Get
            Return Me.m_isHandleCreated
        End Get
    End Property

    Private Function Callback(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal msg As UInteger, ByVal wparam As IntPtr, ByVal lparam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
        Dim m As Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms.Message = Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms.Message.Create(hWnd, CInt(msg), wparam, lparam)
        Me.WndProc(m)
        Return m.Result
    End Function

    Public Sub DefWndProc(ByRef m As Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms.Message)
        If (Me.windowProcHandle = IntPtr.Zero) Then
            m.Result = Win32.NativeMethods.DefWindowProc(m.HWnd, CUInt(m.Msg), m.WParam, m.LParam)
        Else
            m.Result = Win32.NativeMethods.CallWindowProc(Me.windowProcHandle, m.HWnd, CUInt(m.Msg), m.WParam, m.LParam)
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Me.UnhookWindoProc()
        Me.m_isDisposed = True
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Sub

    Private Sub HookWindowProc()
        Me.UnhookWindoProc()
        Dim hWnd As IntPtr = MyBase.Handle
        If (hWnd <> IntPtr.Zero) Then
            Dim [error] As Exception = Nothing
            SyncLock Me
                Me.windowProcHandle = Win32.NativeMethods.GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, Win32.GWL.WNDPROC)
                If (Me.windowProcHandle <> IntPtr.Zero) Then
                    Try
                        Me.windowProcDelegate = New Win32.WindowProc(AddressOf Me.Callback)
                        Me.windowProcRoot = GCHandle.Alloc(Me.windowProcDelegate)
                        Win32.NativeMethods.SetWindowLongDlg(hWnd, Win32.GWL.WNDPROC, Me.windowProcDelegate)
                        Me.windowProcHWnd = hWnd
                        Me.windowProcHooked = True
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        Me.windowProcRoot.Free()
                        Me.windowProcDelegate = Nothing
                        Me.windowProcHandle = IntPtr.Zero
                        Me.windowProcHWnd = IntPtr.Zero
                        Me.windowProcHooked = False
                        [error] = ex
                    End Try
                End If
            End SyncLock
            If (Not [error] Is Nothing) Then
                Throw [error]
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnHandleCreated(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Me.m_isHandleCreated = True
        MyBase.OnHandleCreated(e)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnHandleDestroyed(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Me.m_isHandleCreated = False
        MyBase.OnHandleDestroyed(e)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnParentChanged(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Me.UnhookWindoProc()
        If (Me.DesignMode) Then
            'TODO: Uncomment to make Visal Studio crash.
            'Me.HookWindowProc() 
        Else
            Me.HookWindowProc()
        End If
        Me.UpdateStyles()
        MyBase.OnParentChanged(e)
    End Sub

    Private Function ShouldSerializeBorderStyle() As Boolean
        Return (Me.m_borderStyle <> Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None)
    End Function

    Public Sub UpdateStyles()
        Dim hWnd As IntPtr = MyBase.Handle
        If (hWnd <> IntPtr.Zero) Then

            Dim style As Win32.WS = DirectCast(CUInt(Win32.NativeMethods.GetWindowLong(hWnd, Win32.GWL.STYLE)), Win32.WS)
            Dim exStyle As Win32.WS_EX = DirectCast(CUInt(Win32.NativeMethods.GetWindowLong(hWnd, Win32.GWL.EXSTYLE)), Win32.WS_EX)

            style = (style And Not Win32.WS.BORDER)
            exStyle = (exStyle And Not Win32.WS_EX.CLIENTEDGE)

            Select Case Me.m_borderStyle
                Case Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D
                    exStyle = (exStyle Or Win32.WS_EX.CLIENTEDGE)
                    Exit Select
                Case Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle
                    style = (style Or Win32.WS.BORDER)
                    Exit Select
                Case Else
                    Exit Select
            End Select

            Win32.NativeMethods.SetWindowLong(hWnd, Win32.GWL.STYLE, CInt(style))
            Win32.NativeMethods.SetWindowLong(hWnd, Win32.GWL.EXSTYLE, CInt(exStyle))
            Win32.NativeMethods.SetWindowPos(hWnd, New IntPtr(Win32.HWND.TOP), 0, 0, 0, 0, (Win32.SWP.DRAWFRAME Or (Win32.SWP.NOACTIVATE Or (Win32.SWP.NOZORDER Or (Win32.SWP.NOMOVE Or Win32.SWP.NOSIZE)))))

        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub UnhookWindoProc()
        If (Me.windowProcHooked) Then
            Dim [error] As Exception = Nothing
            SyncLock Me
                Try
                    Win32.NativeMethods.SetWindowLongPtr(Me.windowProcHWnd, Win32.GWL.WNDPROC, Me.windowProcHandle)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    [error] = ex
                Finally
                    Me.windowProcRoot.Free()
                    Me.windowProcDelegate = Nothing
                    Me.windowProcHandle = IntPtr.Zero
                    Me.windowProcHooked = False
                End Try
            End SyncLock
            If (Not [error] Is Nothing) Then
                Throw [error]
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms.Message)
        Me.DefWndProc(m)
    End Sub

    Private windowProcDelegate As Win32.WindowProc
    Private windowProcHandle As IntPtr
    Private windowProcHWnd As IntPtr
    Private windowProcRoot As GCHandle
    Private windowProcHooked As Boolean

    Private m_borderStyle As BorderStyle
    Private m_isDisposed As Boolean
    Private m_isHandleCreated As Boolean

End Class
```

Comment: Diagnose it by starting VS again and attach it to the 1st instance with Tools + Attach to Process.  This ought to be risky, pretty likely that the designer subclasses the window as well.

Comment: I'll give it a try. The control displayed in VS at design-time is actually, as i'm sure you know, a .net 2.0 control (PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089), even though i'm using the CF version. I read on MSDN that "you cannot change this attribute (GWL_WNDPROC) if the window does not belong to the same process as the calling thread." So if this is the case, do you think it will make VS crash?

Comment: It doesn't run in another process.  A hard crash to the desktop at design time is almost always a StackOverflowException btw.  You get one when the subclassed WndProc calls the original WndProc which calls the subclassed WndProc again.  Not uncommon when a window is subclassed more than once, the order is critical.  So is un-subclassing it again, that often goes wrong too.

Comment: Yeah, I see why/how this becomes a problem. Well, in my ongoing quest I found this info on MSDN about [subclassing controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773183(v=vs.85).aspx) and thought maybe the methods in `ComCtl32` could be of some use. But I couldn't find the proc address so no luck. I'm having a hard time accepting that this can't be done, but then again, it begins to draw on me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally! I solved it! By using `SetWindowsHookEx` and `WH_CALLWNDPROC` I can now, at least, track the window messages. Note that I've separated the native calls into two namespaces, `Win32` and `WinCE`.

**Custom control**

```
Public Class SystemControl
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Control

    Public Sub New()
        If (WinCE.NativeMethods.Invokable) Then
            'TODO: WinCE = SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_WNDPROC, WNDPROC)
        ElseIf (Win32.NativeMethods.Invokable) Then
            Me.HookCallWnd32Proc()
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Me.UnhookCallWnd32Proc()
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Sub

    Private Function CallWnd32ProcCallback(ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
        SyncLock Me
            If ((nCode >= 0) AndAlso (lParam <> IntPtr.Zero)) Then
                Dim cwp As Win32.CWPSTRUCT = New Win32.CWPSTRUCT()
                Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, cwp)
                If (cwp.hWnd = Me.Handle) Then
                    Select Case cwp.message
                        Case Win32.WM.MOUSEMOVE
                            'Do something...
                            Exit Select
                        Case Win32.WM.LBUTTONDOWN
                            'Do something...
                            Exit Select
                        Case Else
                            Exit Select
                    End Select
                End If
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(cwp, lParam, True)
            End If
            Return Win32.NativeMethods.CallNextHookEx(IntPtr.Zero, nCode, wParam, lParam)
        End SyncLock
    End Function

    Private Sub HookCallWnd32Proc()
        SyncLock Me
            If (Me._callWndProcHandle = IntPtr.Zero) Then
                Dim threadID As Integer = Win32.NativeMethods.GetCurrentThreadId()
                Dim proc As New Win32.HookProc(AddressOf Me.CallWnd32ProcCallback)
                Dim hHook As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
                Me._callWndProcRoot = GCHandle.Alloc(proc)
                hHook = Win32.NativeMethods.SetWindowsHookEx(Win32.WH.CALLWNDPROC, proc, IntPtr.Zero, threadID)
                If (hHook <> IntPtr.Zero) Then
                    Me._callWndProcHandle = hHook
                    Me._callWndProcHooked = True
                Else
                    Me._callWndProcRoot.Free()
                End If
            End If
        End SyncLock
    End Sub

    Private Sub UnhookCallWnd32Proc()
        SyncLock Me
            If (Me._callWndProcHandle <> IntPtr.Zero) Then
                Win32.NativeMethods.UnhookWindowsHookEx(Me._callWndProcHandle)
                Me._callWndProcRoot.Free()
                Me._callWndProcHandle = IntPtr.Zero
                Me._callWndProcHooked = True
            End If
        End SyncLock
    End Sub

    Private _callWndProcHandle As IntPtr
    Private _callWndProcHooked As Boolean
    Private _callWndProcRoot As GCHandle

End Class
```

**Win32 namespace**

```
Friend NotInheritable Class NativeMethods

    Shared Sub New()
    End Sub

    Private Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Assembly() As System.Reflection.Assembly
        Get
            If (NativeMethods.m_assembly Is Nothing) Then
                NativeMethods.m_assembly = GetType(Integer).Assembly
            End If
            Return NativeMethods.m_assembly
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Invokable() As Boolean
        Get
            If (Not NativeMethods.m_invokable.HasValue) Then
                Dim assembly As System.Reflection.Assembly = NativeMethods.Assembly
                NativeMethods.m_invokable = New Boolean?((Not [assembly] Is Nothing) AndAlso [assembly].FullName.ToUpper.EndsWith("B77A5C561934E089"))
            End If
            Return NativeMethods.m_invokable.Value
        End Get
    End Property

    <DllImport(user32, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True)> _
    Friend Shared Function CallNextHookEx(ByVal hhk As IntPtr, ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <DllImport(user32, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True)> _
    Friend Shared Function GetWindowThreadProcessId(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, <Out()> ByRef processId As UInteger) As UInteger
    End Function

    <DllImport(user32, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True)> _
    Friend Shared Function SetWindowsHookEx(ByVal idHook As Integer, ByVal lpfn As HookProc, ByVal hmod As IntPtr, ByVal dwThreadId As Integer) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <DllImport(user32, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError:=True)> _
    Friend Shared Function UnhookWindowsHookEx(ByVal hhk As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function

    Private Shared m_assembly As System.Reflection.Assembly
    Private Shared m_invokable As Boolean?

    Public Const user32 As String = "user32.dll"
    Public Const kernel32 As String = "kernel32.dll"
    Public Const ComCtl32 As String = "comctl32.dll"

End Class

'It's important that this a `Class` and NOT a `Structure`, orelse it will cause VS to crash.
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
Friend Class CWPSTRUCT
    Public lParam As IntPtr
    Public wParam As IntPtr
    Public message As UInteger
    Public hWnd As IntPtr
End Class

Friend Enum WH As Integer
    MSGFILTER = -1
    JOURNALRECORD = 0
    JOURNALPLAYBACK = 1
    KEYBOARD = 2
    GETMESSAGE = 3
    CALLWNDPROC = 4
    CBT = 5
    SYSMSGFILTER = 6
    MOUSE = 7
    DEBUG = 9
    SHELL = 10
    FOREGROUNDIDLE = 11
    CALLWNDPROCRET = 12
    KEYBOARD_LL = 13
    MOUSE_LL = 14
End Enum
```